# Puzzling recursion with php

Tags: php, recursion, while-loop, conditional-statements

I  use this code with php:

```
while (0 != $date1 || $this->counter < 5 ) {
    // if ($this->true_cahce_failure ) {
    $this->url= $this->adjust_url_with_www_add($this->url);
    // $this->counter=2;
    // }

    $this->cache_debug("Date".$date1." ".$this->url,"Recursion ".$this->counter);
    $date1 = $this->get_date();
    $this->counter++;
}
$this->cache_debug("Date: ".$date1." ".$this->url,"Loop Done ");
```

Basically the loop should continue until either `$date` is `not 0` or `counter` isn't bigger than `5`. Sometimes the `date1` has got `0` but sometimes not. When it doesn't it should return in the while evaluation, and stop the iteration. But it doesn't do so and the iteration continues.

It only stops with counter reaches 5. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not stopping because your `$this->counter` is still `< 5` when `$date1` is not `0`. If you look at those statements in their `true/false` values, your `while` condition becomes:

```
while( false || true )
```

while `$this->counter` is `< 5` and for any values of `$date`, which would make the execution continue.

You likely want to switch it to

```
while( 0==$date1 && $this->counter<5 )
```

Using `&&` because you want both conditions to be `true`, not just one. Also switching the `!=` to `==` when comparing the date to `0` so it will also stop when you have a non-0 date.

Comment: Okay, I used this:    while( strlen($date1)<2 && $this->counter<5 ){

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use `&&` in your condition instead of `||`.

The way you've written it it will keep going if either condition is true, so it will only stop if they are both false.

**EDIT:** after reading your question more closely, I think you need to use

```
while (0 == $date1 && $this->counter < 5 ) {
```

Comment: it didnt work.. it exits on the first iteration //.. when date is 0